# Add CSS box shadow around the whole DIV

Tags: css

Is it possible to have the shadow surround the entire DIV?

```
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #ccc;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #ccc;
```

I know the order of attributes goes:

- Horizontal offset
- Vertical offset
- Blur radius
- Color

But I wonder if it's possible to make the shadow go all around it instead of showing up only on one edge or side.

Comment: Why a 5px blur for Mozilla and WebKit but 3px for others?

Comment: Because I was on Chrome when testing it, so i've only changed the box-shadow... sorry

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You're offsetting the shadow, so to get it to uniformly surround the box, don't offset it:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
```

Comment: Do accomplish this same thing but without blurring; do `box-shadow:0 0 0 3px #ccc;` (notice the extra 0).

Answer (score 19):

Yes, don't offset vertically or horizontally, and use a relatively large blur radius: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6Snr/)

Also, you can use multiple box-shadows if you separate them with a comma. This will allow you to fine-tune where they blur and how much they extend. The example I provide is indistinguishable from a large `outline`, but it can be fine-tuned significantly more: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6Snr/1/)

You missed the last and most relevant property of `box-shadow`, which is `spread-distance`. You can specify a value for how much the shadow expands or contracts (makes my second example obsolete): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6Snr/2/)

The full property list is:

box-shadow: [horizontal-offset] [vertical-offset] [blur-radius] [spread-distance] [color] inset?

But even better, read through the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#ltshadowgt).

Answer (score 8):

Just use the below code. It will shadow surround the entire DIV

```css
-webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 6):

The CSS code would be:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px white;
```

That will shadow the entire DIV no matter its shape!

Comment: this solution is good

Answer (score 4):

## Use this below code

```
 border:2px soild #eee;

 margin: 15px 15px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 8px #eee;
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 8px #eee;
box-shadow: 2px 3px 8px #eee;
```

## Explanation:-

box-shadow requires you to set the horizontal & vertical offsets, you can then optionally set the blur and colour, you can also choose to have the shadow inset instead of the default outset. Colour can be defined as **hex** or **rgba**.

**box-shadow** : inset/outset h-offset v-offset blur spread color;

Explanation of the values...

**inset/outset** -- whether the shadow is inside or outside the box. If not specified it will default to outset.

**h-offset** -- the horizontal offset of the shadow (required value)

**v-offset** -- the vertical offset of the shadow (required value)

**blur** -- as it says, the blur of the shadow

**spread** -- moves the shadow away from the box equally on all sides. A positive value causes the shadow to expand, negative causes it to contract. Though this value isn't often used, it is useful with multiple shadows.

**color** -- as it says, the color of the shadow

## Usage

box-shadow:2px 3px 8px #eee;  a gray shadow with a horizontal outset of 2px, vertical of 3px and a blur of 8px

Answer (score 0):

```
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: aqua;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px red;
```